# decode text file from GitLab causing UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm retrieving a file from GitLab (which sends files base64 encoded) that contains the tree seen below:

```
$ tree  
.  
├── LICENSE.md  
├── README.md  
├── manifest.yaml  
├── src  
│   ├── workflow.yaml  
│   ├── workflow.json  
│   └── resources  
│       ├── action1.yaml  
│       ├── action2.yaml  
│       ├── subworkflow.yaml  
│       └── template.yaml  
└── install  
    └── workflow.zip
```

How can I decode this and keep the special characters (└,├,─)?

I've tried straight decoding and converting the bytes to string:

```py
def decode(data):
  decoded = base64.b64decode(data)
  return "".join(chr(x) for x in bytearray(decoded))
```

That gives the wrong characters:

```
$ tree
.
â??â??â?? LICENSE.md
â??â??â?? README.md
â??â??â?? manifest.yaml
â??â??â?? src
â??Â Â  â??â??â?? workflow.yaml
â??Â Â  â??â??â?? workflow.json
â??Â Â  â??â??â?? resources
â??Â Â      â??â??â?? action1.yaml
â??Â Â      â??â??â?? action2.yaml
â??Â Â      â??â??â?? subworkflow.yaml
â??Â Â      â??â??â?? template.yaml
â??â??â?? install
 Â Â  â??â??â?? workflow.zip
```

Then tried converting to utf-8 bytes first, but that converts them to question marks:

```py
def decode_data(b64_data):
    b64_bytes = b64_data.encode('utf-8')
    data_bytes = base64.b64decode(b64_bytes)
    return data_bytes.decode('utf-8')
```

What else can I try? I'm using python3.6

Response for GitLab when retrieving the file:

```
{
    "file_name": "README.md",
    "file_path": "README.md",
    "size": 390,
    "encoding": "base64",
    "content_sha256": "b3cbc43cae23d77e09b60a2cb89ce76b969024ba6621548b6d3bc5b2b60380da",
    "ref": "master",
    "blob_id": "b7d9985ac1378310d31b9a8bccfc2cce5ad9655a",
    "commit_id": "bbc71c23657249a924174eca9b025d64b10518fc",
    "last_commit_id": "bbc71c23657249a924174eca9b025d64b10518fc",
    "content": "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"
}
```

Comment: We can't guess the encoding of the original file or which bytes you are reading from it. Please [edit] to show unambiguously what your input is. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Comment: Where does `data` come from and where does base64 encoding fit into the picture here? Neither the input not the output seems to contain any base64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base64 string decodes to a bunch of bytes that you need to decode again, this time with utf-8:

````py
In []: def decode2(data):
  ...:   decoded = base64.b64decode(data)
  ...:   return decoded.decode()
  ...:

In []: print(decode2("IyBUZXN0R2l0CgpgYGAKJCB0cmVlCi4K4pSc4pSA4pSAIExJQ0V
  ...: OU0UubWQK4pSc4pSA4pSAIFJFQURNRS5tZArilJzilIDilIAgbWFuaWZlc3QueWFtb
  ...: ArilJzilIDilIAgc3JjCuKUgsKgwqAg4pSc4pSA4pSAIHdvcmtmbG93LnlhbWwK4pS
  ...: CwqDCoCDilJzilIDilIAgd29ya2Zsb3cuanNvbgrilILCoMKgIOKUlOKUgOKUgCByZ
  ...: XNvdXJjZXMK4pSCwqDCoCAgICAg4pSc4pSA4pSAIGFjdGlvbjEueWFtbArilILCoMK
  ...: gICAgICDilJzilIDilIAgYWN0aW9uMi55YW1sCuKUgsKgwqAgICAgIOKUnOKUgOKUg
  ...: CBzdWJ3b3JrZmxvdy55YW1sCuKUgsKgwqAgICAgIOKUlOKUgOKUgCB0ZW1wbGF0ZS5
  ...: 5YW1sCuKUlOKUgOKUgCBpbnN0YWxsCiDCoMKgIOKUlOKUgOKUgCB3b3JrZmxvdy56a
  ...: XAKYGBg"))
# TestGit

```
$ tree
.
├── LICENSE.md
├── README.md
├── manifest.yaml
├── src
│   ├── workflow.yaml
│   ├── workflow.json
│   └── resources
│       ├── action1.yaml
│       ├── action2.yaml
│       ├── subworkflow.yaml
│       └── template.yaml
└── install
    └── workflow.zip
```
````

In case it is throwing `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position ...` when outputting to console, you have to set the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable to `utf-8`:

- Unix: `export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8`
- Windows: `set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8`

Comment: When I try that, I get a UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 24-26: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Quite strange that it seems to be trying to encode rather than decode. Anyway, can you try `.decode("utf-8")` instead of just `.decode()`?

Comment: It's the same error. Is it possible this has to do with my console? I can't even paste that output

Comment: According to a comment below [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9942822/14222267) yes it may be associated with your console. So perhaps you should try executing `export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` prior to running the script, unless you're on Windows, in which case I think it's `set` rather than `export`.

Comment: That did it. Please add that to you answer and I'll mark it as good :)

Comment: Great to hear that it worked for you. I've updated the answer.